# How to monitor VOIP packets

Tags: voip

We have Asterisk server configured in a Cent OS 5.5. Sometimes my colleague complains
that the quality of the call is not good.

1. How can I monitor the incoming or outgoing VOIP packets ?
2. Is there a way to investigate amount of VOIP packets loss ?

Answer (score 4):

Use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) to capture and analyse the network traffic. This will allows you to look at packet loss on the audio (RTP) stream, and even listen to it (Remember to warn the users that you will be monitoring their communications during your troubleshooting).

If your server does not have a graphical desktop use tshark instead. This will allow you to save a capture file and analyse it later once you have downloaded it to your desktop, where you will need to install Wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I monitor the incoming or outgoing VOIP packets ?

- For count packages(byte) use iptables rules
- For collecting traffic statistic use NetFlow
- For runtime monitoring use iptraf

> Is there a way to investigate amount of VOIP packets loss ?

I use [VoIPmonitor](http://www.voipmonitor.org/). Many SIP clients have built-in functions.

Answer (score 1):

tcpdump, specifically looking at port 5060 for sip traffic. You can view captures in Wireshark.